# updating the nested array's object in mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update the nested array's object but failing . I wanted to update the any one object in modules array based on id query. Below are the queries I have tried to get the desired output but the query whatever I have tried is giving same previous output than I need.

```
{
 "_id": {
   "$oid": "644f9cbf65e47d951ac1c799"
 },
 "appStoreId": "123456",
 "tenantId": "6367eec0c3e77bde80d31a1d",
 "sites": [
   {
     "siteId": "620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb",
     "name": "Site One",
     "priority": 1,
     "utcTimeOffset": "utcTimeOffset",
     "modules": [
       {
         "moduleId": "644fd5f7d6c546b52ca7f861",
         "name": "Ravi",
         "shortDescription": "This is my description",
         
         "priority": 1,
         "displayFor": [
           "FOOTER"
         ],
         "moduleIdentifier": "DINING",
         "_id": {
           "$oid": "644fd8c4407d1384688ba9c9"
         }
       },
       {
         "moduleId": "644fd5ced6c546b52ca7f84e",
         "name": "Anonymous",
         "shortDescription": "This is short Description for Dining",
   
         "priority": 1,
         "displayFor": [
           "HOME"
         ],
         "moduleIdentifier": "FFF",
         "_id": {
           "$oid": "644fd5ced6c546b52ca7f84f"
         }
       },
       {
         "moduleId": "644fd5e8d6c546b52ca7f859",
         "name": "HOME",
         "shortDescription": "This is short Description for Dining",
         "priority": 1,
         "displayFor": [
           "HOME"
         ],
         "moduleIdentifier": "DINING",
         "_id": {
           "$oid": "644fd5e8d6c546b52ca7f85a"
         }
       },
       {
         "moduleId": "644fd5f7d6c546b52ca7f861",
         "name": "GAMING",
         "shortDescription": "This is short Description for Dining",
         "priority": 1,
         "displayFor": [
           "HOME"
         ],
         "moduleIdentifier": "GAMING",
         "_id": {
           "$oid": "644fd5f7d6c546b52ca7f862"
         }
       }
     ],
     "additionalProperties": {
       "noOfPromotionsOnHomeTab": 1
     },
     "_id": {
       "$oid": "620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb"
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Queries I have tried :
1.

```
   db.collection.update({
  _id: "644f9cbf65e47d951ac1c799",
  sites: {
    $elemMatch: {
      siteId: {
        "$oid": "620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  $set: {
    "sites.$[outer].modules.$[inner].name": "HOUSE"
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "outer.siteId": {
        "$oid": "620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb"
      }
    },
    {
      "inner.moduleId": {
        "$oid": "644fd5f7d6c546b52ca7f861"
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

2. 

```
    db.collection.updateOne(
    {
        _id: {"$oid": '644f9cbf65e47d951ac1c799'},
        sites:{$elemMatch: {siteId: {"$oid":"620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb"}}}

    },
    {
        $set:{"sites.$[outer].modules.$[inner].name":"HOUSE"}
    },
    {
        arrayFilters:[{"outer.siteId":{"$oid":"620a310edefb1c43e9d5b0bb"}},{"inner.moduleId":{"$oid":"644fd5f7d6c546b52ca7f861"}}]
    }
)
```